# Controls disabled after code executed XCode 4.5 iOS 6

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I've created an app which uses the following:

SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter

The code seems to work OK and makes the posts to Facebook and Twitter but then once the posts have been completed and I return back to the app view none of the controls are active and I have to close the app and relaunch for them to work again.

I think I have nested to code incorrectly in the IF statement (posted below), so was wondering if anybody could offer any advice.

I'm very new to Xcode etc so please be patient and kind to me :-)

Thanks in advance

Pete

```
- (IBAction)postButton:(id)sender
```

{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])

```
{
    SLComposeViewController *facebook = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];

    ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]);

    {
        SLComposeViewController *twitter = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];

        facebook = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [facebook setInitialText:[[self statusMessage]text]];

        twitter = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [twitter setInitialText:[[self statusMessage]text]];

        [self presentViewController:facebook animated:YES completion:nil];

        [facebook setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)

        {
            NSString *output;
            switch (result)
            {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    output = @"Action Cancelled";
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    output = @"Post Sucessfull";
                default:
                    break;
            }

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

            [twitter setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)

            {
                NSString *output;
                switch (result)

                {
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                        output = @"Action Cancelled";
                        break;
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                        output = @"Tweet Sucessfull";
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];

            }];
        }

         ];}
}
```

}